# Cannot import anything from kombu

Tags: python, kombu

I'm pretty confused here. I'm following the kombu docs word for word. I'm running inside of a virtual environment. Has anyone had a similar issue?

```
(pipes)slim-2:consumers ryan$ pip install kombu
Downloading/unpacking kombu
  Downloading kombu-3.0.24-py2.py3-none-any.whl (238kB): 238kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking amqp>=1.4.5,<2.0 (from kombu)
  Downloading amqp-1.4.6-py2-none-any.whl (49kB): 49kB downloaded
Downloading/unpacking anyjson>=0.3.3 (from kombu)
  Downloading anyjson-0.3.3.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:/Users/ryan/.virtualenvs/pipes/build/anyjson/setup.py) egg_info for package anyjson

Installing collected packages: kombu, amqp, anyjson
  Running setup.py install for anyjson

Successfully installed kombu amqp anyjson
Cleaning up...

(pipes)slim-2:consumers ryan$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from kombu import Connection
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "kombu.py", line 9, in <module>
    from kombu import Connection
ImportError: cannot import name Connection
>>>
```

Comment: Looks like there may be some type of conflict with a kombu package in stdlib? If I start with a clean environment, and try "import kombu" python complains about not knowing about the requests library (line 9 of kombu.py) instead of saying "No module named kombu"

Comment: Maybe, in your current directory (`(pipes)slim-2:consumers ryan$`), do you have some folder named `kombu` with empty `__init__.py`?

Comment: Ah!, that's it. Thanks Valijon. I feel silly